# Most efficient and straightforward way to collect dropwizard metrics and send them to Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dropwizard, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.2/docs/) based application running on [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/). I'm already collecting lots of application specific metrics using [dropwizard metrics support](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/).

I know it can report metrics via [HTTP](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#reporting-via-http), [JMX](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#reporting-via-jmx), CSV, [collectd](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/tree/master/metrics-collectd), etc.

**I want to send these metrics to Stackdriver.**

Three alternatives came to mind:

1. build a new metric reporter using [Stackdriver Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics)
2. create a new [Stackdriver monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) flavor
3. create a sidecar container that collects metrics (shared file or http polling) and send them to StackDriver (API ? collectd ?)

What would be the most efficient and straighforward way to achieve that ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is an excellent question but may not lend itself well to Stack Overflow.  I suspect answers to this question would lend themselves well to opinion based on people's experience rather than solutions based on empirical evidence and documentation.  I believe the [Kubernetes Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kubernetes-users) would be an excellent forum for this sort of discussion-based question.  I encourage you to post it there.  The community there is very active.  I suggest you mention how you would use each example (in their own pod or existing pod, etc.).

Comment: If you've already done so, feel free to post a link to that thread here so that others encountering this question and also interested in the answers may follow through.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/-iRImPgAoRM